# What kind of data does RealPopup send through the mailslot?

Tags: c#, c++, interop, mailslot

I'm trying to create an app that mimics RealPopup and I will be using it as a proof of concept for sending out computer-generated notifications to clients which are already using RealPopup throughout our company network.

I have already created my own mailslot and can send and receive data from one PC to another. Now the problem, whenever I listen to RealPopup's mailslot (\\.\mailslot\realp), I only get "1" even though I sent a longer string (like "Hello World" for example) from a PC using RealPopup.

Is RealPopup sending to a different mailslot other than the currently listening one?

[edit]

I think I got it. It's sending a byte array that's probably be a C++ structure. I just have to figure out the structure which is next to impossible (afaik) since RealPopUp isn't open source. Ah well.

Answer (score 1):

hi there from RealPopup author. :) you can find some information about the custom protocol I implemented over mailslots [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/CSharedMailslot.aspx) on CodeProject. let me know if you need more info.